# How psql's \dt PATTERN works?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I try to list trigger. I know that trigger contain `new` word.
I try to find trigger by that word but nothing is found:

```
tucha=> \dft new
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)

tucha=> \dft xxx_child_fk_check_new 
                                List of functions
 Schema |          Name          | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
--------+------------------------+------------------+---------------------+------
 public | xxx_child_fk_check_new | trigger          |                     | func
(1 row)
```

I suppose that `PATTERN` is regex, but it does not work.

What `PATTERN` is? and how to find my trigger by `new`?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
\dFt *new*
```

Or if you want to search in all schemas:

```
\dFt *.*new*
```